# Compile for use with VNC/remote X server

Tags: config

I'm trying to connect from a PC to a remote Centos 7 server, and I'd like to run a graphical emacs over VNC. The server's completely locked down, but I can copy RPMs to it.

I've tried installing emacs by copying over various base RPMs, but ImageMagick has too many dependencies, and X appears to be hobbled as well. So, next step, compile from source.

I've just tried a first attempt at configuring without ImageMagick, but configure complains that I'm missing X stuff.

Dumb question: what does `--without-x` actually mean? Can I compile without X, with my local X server magically producing a graphical emacs?

And, since the answer to that is almost certainly 'no', I don't suppose there's a list of basic dependencices anywhere? Note that running `yum` is not an option, since it assumes network access - everything has to be done with one RPM at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--without-x` means that the compiled Emacs will only run in a terminal. If `configure` complains that you are missing a dependency, then what you are really missing is a devel package for that dependency. This package has the headers needed to compile a program that uses a library provided by the dependency. The headers do not need to be installed on the computer where Emacs will run, only on the computer where it is built.

That said, you’ll be happier using TRAMP. Run Emacs on your own machine, then open a file on the server by typing in `/ssh:remote:path/to/file`. If you configure ssh to use key–based authentication instead of password authentication, then Emacs will never need to ask for a password. I highly recommend also configuring ssh with `ControlMaster on`, so that multiple ssh sessions to the same destination all end up tunneled over a single TCP connection. This noticeably reduces the amount of time needed to start a new session, which is something TRAMP must do from time to time.

Comment: TRAMP sounds good. `--without-x` was Ok-ish, but is basically (entirely?) emacs-nox. Compiling *with* X is next to impossible if you're just working with RPMs - you probably need about 100 of them. I eventually realised that I could just copy the entire Centos install ISO over the vpn to the server, and just `yum install emacs`, which does it properly. Now just waiting for a knock on the door from the sysadmins... :)

Comment: :) Note that you only need those dependencies on the computer where you build Emacs. There should only be about half a dozen, not literally a hundred, but it is a real shame that there is no list you can consult ahead of time. You could grovel in the `configure` script to find them all, but that would be really annoying (readability is never a priority in the `configure` script). The usual strategy is to just run `configure`, fixing each problem it finds in turn, and eventually it will be happy. Objectively this sucks, but back when it was invented it was better than the alternatives.